# Printing Name of Column after Group By in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy, matplotlib

I have one data frame on which I perform the group by clause, now I need to print the columns by which I had done group by clause
The below image is the output of the code now I need to print the first column of output(STRSTATE), insort the output should be 'OR' not the entire row

```
Gb = df.groupby('STRSTATE').count().sort_values(by='date_super')[6:7]
Gb
```

[image: This is the output of code now I need to print the first column of output(STRSTATE), insort the output should be 'OR' not the entire row]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want, but maybe this helps you out

```
Gb = df.groupby('STRSTATE').count().sort_values(by='date_super').index
Gb[6:7] # this will give you 'OR'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, this work is partially correct, it returns OR but in a different format  like this       Index(['OR'], dtype='object', name='STRSTATE')  is there any way I can access ['OR']

Comment: yea you can do this in two ways:
1) 
Gb = list(df.groupby('STRSTATE').count().sort_values(by='date_super').index)
Gb[6:7] # this will give you what you want ['OR']

2) Gb like before,
Gb[6:7][0] # this will give you just 'OR'